# How to make a nested List form a List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want a nested list like this:

```
{{"a","b","c","d"}, {"e","f"}, {"g"}}
```

from this list:

```
{"a","b","c","d","*","e","f","*","g"}
```

"*" is a delimiter for splitting the list.

I believe that there is a elegant LINQ way to do this but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a approach with classy foreach-loop

```
List<string> input = new List<string>(){"a","b","c","d","*","e","f","*","g"};
List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in input)
{
    if (item == "*")
    {
        result.Add(temp);
        temp = new List<string>();
    }
    else
    {
        temp.Add(item);
    }
}
result.Add(temp);
```

Comment: I think your way is the most readable in all answers. Easy to understand, No index calculation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Good news. You don't even need LINQ:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "*", "e", "f", "*", "g" };
var newList = String.Concat(list).Split('*').ToList();
```

*(Unless you count the `ToList`, I suppose.)*

Comment: @user1429080 Try it yourself.

Comment: The solution is correct if and only if all the items in the `list` are *one character strings* only. Possible counter exanple: `var input = new List<string>() { "abc", "d", "*", "ef", "ghi"};`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko True, but I'll leave this answer up in case that's not an issue for OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for *Linq*, you can try `GroupBy`:

```
  List<string> source = new List<string>() { 
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "*", "e", "f", "*", "g" };

  int index = 0;

  List<List<string>> result = source
    .Select(item => new {
       item = item,
       index = item == "*" ? ++index : index })
    .Where(chunk => chunk.item != "*")
    .GroupBy(chunk => chunk.index, 
             chunk => chunk.item)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Test:

```
  string test = "{" + string.Join(", ", result
    .Select(line => "{" + string.Join(", ", line) + "}")) + "}" ;

  Console.Write(test);
```

Outcome:

```
  {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g}}
```

An alternative, no *Linq* but simple loop method:

```
  List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string>(),
  };

  foreach (var item in source)
    if (item == "*")
      result.Add(new List<string>());
    else
      result[result.Count - 1].Add(item);
```

Comment: Nice try according OP request but LINQ is not always the way to go. Old fashioned C# will be definitely more readable !

Comment: I believed that LINQ was the best way but that was a mistake. Thanks!